# timezone displays incorrect location

Tags: php

Running v. 7.2.5, regardless of which America I use, I keep getting Europe/Berlin returned.   Could it be because of these default longitudes and latitudes. where ever they're located and set?

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone=America/New_York

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333
```

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo()` to make sure you're modifying the *right* `php.ini` file. There may be several at times. Then make sure you've restarted the webserver and/or PHP-FPM if you're using that.

Comment: and `php -i | grep timezone` on the command line - that can also frequently be a different configuration file.

Comment: @David Hahn, if i helped to answer your question, could you accept my answer, please? Thanks

Comment: @Casper Wilkes I did fix it in the php.ini; I just dont recall now what I did. unfortunately too your answer doesn't even sound close, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted your web-server? Apache & others actually cache the config options and will not use newly set options until the web-server has been restarted.

Here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/star-stop-restart-apache2-webserver/ are some start/stop/restart directions for various servers.

Comment: Oh I wish I could remember exactly what I did to fix it; but it involved changes to php.ini